# Why const references suppress automatic conversion in C++

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, const-reference

In the book "Introduction to Design Patterns in C++ with Qt" I found
"It is still slightly faster to pass by const reference, which enables C++ to optimize out the copy operation entirely. With const reference, the function cannot make changes to the reference, and automatic conversions do not happen."

What does it mean by "automatic conversions do not happen"?

Comment: He's maybe referring to `function-to-pointer` and `array-to-pointer` conversions on function parameters.